cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.0-windows10' not found
Suppression State
Error (active)  MSB4184 The expression """.0-windows10" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.0-windows10' not found.  MauiApp1 (net8.0-android), MauiApp1 (net8.0-ios), MauiApp1 (net8.0-maccatalyst), MauiApp1 (net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0)
[tag:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets   273
]
how to fix it???
i,m use vs 2022 and when bulid i have this error

We'll need more information than that. I suspect it's a problem in the project file. If you start a brand new Maui project, do you get the issue at that point? Have you looked at everything that mentions windows10 in your project file?

I'm Update Vs 2022 to VS Preview version and fixed it 

Maybe you miss the topic Can I accept my own question? from the SO blog.
